# Convert M3U8 playlist to MP4 using GStreamer

Tags: video, ffmpeg, gstreamer, h.264, http-live-streaming

I'm trying to convert an HLS playlist to MP4 file. The .ts files in the list are guaranteed to be h264/aac and with the same resolution (for cases when there is a EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY tag).

this is the closes I got to a working pipeline:

```
gst-launch-1.0 mp4mux name=mux ! filesink location=x.mp4 souphttpsrc location="https://remote/path/to/index.m3u8" ! decodebin name=decode ! videoconvert ! queue ! x264enc ! mux. decode. ! audioconvert ! avenc_aac ! mux.
```

Don't really know if the result is valid as this command line gets GStreamer to play the HLS in `playing` time instead of fast forward and ingest as fast as possible (the list is closed with `#EXT-X-ENDLIST`).

Second issue is that it looks to me like this pipeline is encoding the stream instead of just coping it. I don't need it to encode, only change the container. H264/aac in the .TS files is what I also need in the .MP4 file.

So, is it possible to only copy and not transcode using as-fast-as-u-can ingestion and not real-life speed?

Basically, I am trying to find the GStreamer equivalent to this FFmpeg command:

```
FFmpeg -i "https://remote/path/to/index.m3u8" -c copy x.mp4
```

(I have to use GStreamer and not FFmpeg.)

Answer (score 0):

Can do that with this:

```
gst-launch-1.0 souphttpsrc location=file.n3u8 ! hlsdemux ! filesink location=videoOut.mp4 -e
```

Answer (score 0):

```
gst-launch-1.0 mp4mux name=outmux ! filesink location="x.mp4" souphttpsrc location=https://remote/path/to/index.m3u8 ! hlsdemux ! tsdemux name=mux  mux.video_0_0100 ! queue ! h264parse ! outmux.video_0 mux.audio_0_0101 ! queue ! aacparse ! outmux.audio_0
```

The other answer that demuxes the HLS feed with `hlsdemux` and writes to an mp4 can also work, but the file might not play everywhere because it is still a TS stream. For example, some web browsers might have a hard time playing it.

The above command will further demux the TS stream into a video and audio stream, and then muxes them into an MP4 using `mp4mux` (you can also use `qtmux` if you have it available).